# Switching between branches with long names in Git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Is there an easy way to switch between branches without typing long branch names? I can presumably refer to the latest commit in the branch with a hash. But how do I get the hash while having another branch checked out?

I would like to do something like:

```
> git branch -a
master ab12cd...
feature/separate-sound-channels 34efgh...
> git checkout 34efgh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply checkout the hash because, while that will get the correct commit, it will put you in "detached HEAD" state, which basically means your working copy isn't associated with a specific branch and so git commands that move a branch label around won't know which branch to affect.

As @John Zwinck mentions, `git-completion.bash` will perform head-completion (among other niceties) when you type a git command and hit tab when a head name (branch or tag) is expected next on the command line:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion

```
mouse:~/Documents/workspace/jackson-core (master) $ git branch -a
* master
  temp
  remotes/origin/2.0
...
mouse:~/Documents/workspace/jackson-core (master) $ git tag
2.1.0b
2.1.1b
jackson-core-2.0.0
jackson-core-2.0.0-RC1
...
mouse:~/Documents/workspace/jackson-core (master) $ git checkout <tab>
2.0                      jackson-core-2.0.0-RC3   jackson-core-2.2.1
2.1                      jackson-core-2.0.1       jackson-core-2.2.2
2.1.0b                   jackson-core-2.0.2       master
2.1.1b                   jackson-core-2.0.4       origin/2.0
2.2                      jackson-core-2.0.5       origin/2.1
FETCH_HEAD               jackson-core-2.0.6       origin/2.2
HEAD                     jackson-core-2.1.2       origin/HEAD
ORIG_HEAD                jackson-core-2.1.3       origin/gh-pages
gh-pages                 jackson-core-2.1.4       origin/master
jackson-core-2.0.0       jackson-core-2.1.5       temp
jackson-core-2.0.0-RC1   jackson-core-2.2.0-rc1
jackson-core-2.0.0-RC2   jackson-core-2.2.0b
mouse:~/Documents/workspace/jackson-core (master) $ git checkout 2.<tab>
2.0      2.1      2.1.0b   2.1.1b   2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about with tab-completion?
http://code-worrier.com/blog/autocomplete-git/